# enviar imagen2 como campo input file a base de datos - php

Tags: php

Buen dia, tengo una pregunta puntual, necesito que el campo "imagen2" cuando entre en el post se envié como formato file "archivo" y no como input de texto, he intentado pero lo único que encontré fue un ejemplo que lo coloque en comentarios en el codigo pero no he logrado implementarlo.

```html
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');
require_once('api.php');
require_once('cors.php');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method=="POST"){
    $json = null;
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $nombre = $data['nombre'];
    $precio = $data['precio'];
    $imagen2 = $data['imagen2'];
    $api = new Api();
    $json = $api->addProducto($nombre, $precio, $imagen2);
    echo $json;
}

 //$imagen2 = (file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name']));



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

quite la variable de $data e implemente la variable $imagen2 que utiliza "file_get_contents" y llama a "FILE" en vez de "input", y las demás variables que utilizaban la variable $data la cambie por "$_POST".

```html
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');
require_once('api.php');
require_once('cors.php');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

/* Ahora */
if($method=="POST"){
    $json = null;
    $imagen2 = (file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name']));
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $precio = $_POST['precio'];
    $api = new Api();
    $json = $api->addProducto($nombre, $precio, $imagen2);
    echo $json;
}

/* antes*/
if($method=="POST"){
    $json = null;
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $nombre = $data['nombre'];
    $precio = $data['precio'];
    $imagen2 = $data['imagen2'];
    $api = new Api();
    $json = $api->addProducto($nombre, $precio, $imagen2);
    echo $json;
}*/



?>
```